# How can I get vboxwebsrv load automatically on boot

Tags: virtualbox

Just trying to get the phpvirtualbox page on the new 16.04
Could not have vboxwebsrv service load on boot by default and Oracle's manuals does not help on that.
Anyone have any hints on that?..

Comment: Just entered this command and it solved the problem:`sudo systemctl enable vboxweb.service`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl enable vboxweb.service
```

I have sorted it out for myself. Hope it helps other peeps here.